# CodeIgniter: connecting to MS SQL database seems to crash app

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I'm starting a new CI application but this time connecting to a MS SQL database opposed to a MySQL db like I usually do.

I've setup my MVC and got my view rendered as usual. I've added the database connection data and loaded the database library. Now I'm just seeing a blank screen. My view seems to not be loading due to the database connection.

```
$active_group = 'clientportal';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['clientportal']['hostname'] = 'JURA';
$db['clientportal']['username'] = 'sa';
$db['clientportal']['password'] = '*********';
$db['clientportal']['database'] = 'ClientPortal';
$db['clientportal']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
$db['clientportal']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['clientportal']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['clientportal']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['clientportal']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['clientportal']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['clientportal']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['clientportal']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['clientportal']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['clientportal']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['clientportal']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I've checked the sever is on, etc. I know these details are correct as I've connected to it before using PHP. I know I've not provided much information but can anyone shed some light on what might be happening?

I'm using CI v2. SQL Server 2008

Thanks,

Billy

Comment: Do the CI logs provide any clues? If so, could you add its ouput to the question?

Comment: I've changed my driver. I've downloaded the CI sqlsrv driver someone posted. Can't quite remember where but I'llfind it and post the link.

Comment: When using the CI sqlsrv driver did you have to tweak anything else or did it all just kick into play? Interested as I have the very same issue. The link for CI sqlsrv BTW is http://www.kaweb.co.uk/uncategorized/mssql-server-2005-and-codeigniter/

Comment: @Nathan I think I just stuck it in extensions and linked it in my PHP config.ini file plus if you're using active record and the db config file that comes with CI you have to change the driver to the new one: $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';

Comment: @iamjonesy - were you able to fix this and if so, how? I am experiencing the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple issues like this, it all came down to the PHP enabled MSSQL driver. I had issues with versions of PHP like:

- 5.2.12

but a version like

- 5.2.17 worked just fine (I am recalling ver numbers here so don't hold me to it).

It all comes down to your **MSSQL extension**.  I've even witnessed the earlier version go out over port **445** and the newer version over **1433**

Check your PHP version, review if there are known PHP MSSQL conflicts, if all else fails try updating.

Thats what solved it for me. And yeah CodeIgniter SHOULD have a means to give extra details on MSSQL connection errors, a blank page is NOT very useful. And turning debugging to full only results in a 'HALT' after the database leading message.